# Cannot parse response

Tags: android, jackson, retrofit

I have problem with deserialization of json response using JacksonConverter and Retrofit-2.0.0-beta2. When I have passing the request I got Exception:

> 10-19 16:14:21.918 31481-31481/? W/System.err:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character
>   ('﻿' (code 65279 / 0xfeff)): expected a valid value (number, String,
>   array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') 10-19 16:14:21.918
>   31481-31481/? W/System.err:  at [Source:
>   java.io.InputStreamReader@edac0ef; line: 2, column: 2] 10-19
>   16:14:21.918 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1419)
>   10-19 16:14:21.918 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:508)
>   10-19 16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:437)
>   10-19 16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1462)
>   10-19 16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:683)
>   10-19 16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._initForReading(ObjectReader.java:1346)
>   10-19 16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1252)
>   10-19 16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:880)
>   10-19 16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit.JacksonResponseBodyConverter.convert(JacksonResponseBodyConverter.java:33)
>   10-19 16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit.JacksonResponseBodyConverter.convert(JacksonResponseBodyConverter.java:23)
>   10-19 16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:148) 10-19
>   16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit.OkHttpCall.access$100(OkHttpCall.java:29) 10-19 16:14:21.919
>   31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:94) 10-19
>   16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:168) 10-19
>   16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
>   10-19 16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   10-19 16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   10-19 16:14:21.919 31481-31481/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

I cannot change response JSON. Tak a look at my Retrofit configuration:

```
        sInstance = new RetrofitRequestCreator();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true);
        sInstance.mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(
                JacksonConverterFactory.create(mapper)).build();
```

**Gradle.build**

```
...
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta2'
...
```

Is there any method to escape this character? Thank You for all your replies

Comment: the json seems invalid. post it.

Comment: 0xfeff is a `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE` http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0xFEFF/index.html It has nothing to do in the structure of a json file (it could be found inside a string, and that would not cause that issue). Find whoever wrote the json formatter for the service you are using and yell at them.

Comment: Thank for your advice. Json is generated by wp-api https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/ I thought that there is any method to escape certain characters before parsing. thank You

Answer (score -2):

You need to include all dependencies.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-datatype-json-org:1.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Comment: As I know retrofit 2.0 has built-in okhttp